# Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: image/jpeg....... Blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I used blueimp jquery file upload plugin in a project, it is working fine on localhost, but reverse is the case on the online server, each time i try to upload, the progress bar will move from 0% to 100%, then it waits for some time then i get this error **File upload aborted** without clicking on the **Abort** button during upload and in my console as well i get **Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: image/jpeg** each time i select an image file of any format (PNG, GIF, JPG...) both on localhost and online server, please how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the plugin is working on localhost and not working on the online server was due to the **insufficient permission** for the **Uploadhandler.php** to write any uploaded file to the upload directory **server/php/files** on the **blueimp jquery file upload** all you need to do is: 
**N:B** this solution is not for just **blueimp jquery file upload** it can also help solve any upload problem similar to this using any other upload handler or plugin
*If you have an SSH access to your server*
Run this linux command

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

and look at the left-most column corresponding to the Apache server. This is the user that is running Apache, and by inheritance also PHP.
Assuming the upload directory is **uploads** with respect to the home directory, run the following commands one line after the other

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/uploads
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/uploads
```